# Java, split string by punctuation sign, process string, add punctuation signs back to string

Tags: java, string

I have string like this:

```
Some text, with punctuation sign!
```

I am splitting it by punctuation signs, using `str.split("regex")`. Then I process each element (switch characters) in the received array, after splitting.

And I want to add all punctuation signs back to their places. So result should be like this:

```
Smoe txet, wtih pinctuatuon sgin!
```

What is the best approach to do that?

Comment: When you do this `str.split("regex")` you split by the 1 punctuation sign or there could be many?

Comment: f you're splitting by one symbol, say `str.split(",")` then you know that the array you're getting contains only the words and after processing you can put your signs back after each array element... but I gess it is not the case.. :)

Yes, @rich is right, the approach with split won't work here. You'll have to traverse it one by one character...

Comment: @ACV. It could be many, e.g ".,:;!?"

Answer (score 2):

How about doing the whole thing in one tiny line?

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\b\\w)(.)(.)", "$2$1");
```

---

Some test code:

```
String str = "Some text, with punctuation sign!";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?<=\\b\\w)(.)(.)", "$2$1"));
```

Output:

```
Smoe txet, wtih pnuctuation sgin!
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I like this regex :D.

Comment: @Tom LOL! I **see** what you mean :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd read through the string character by character.

- If the character is punctuation append it to a StringBuilder
- If the character is not punctuation keep reading characters until you reach a punctuation character, then process that word and append it to the StringBuilder.
  Then skip to that next punctuation character.

This prints, rather than appends to a StringBuilder, but you get the idea:

```
String sentence = "This is a test, message!";
for (int i = 0; i<sentence.length(); i++) {
  if (Character.isLetter(sentence.charAt(i))) {
    String tmp = "" +sentence.charAt(i);
    while (Character.isLetter(sentence.charAt(i+1)) && i<sentence.length()) {
      i++;
      tmp += sentence.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.print(switchChars(tmp));
  } else {
    System.out.print(sentence.charAt(i));
  }
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this approach.

Comment: After iteration of the last character we would received index out... `while (Character.isLetter(sentence.charAt(i+1)) && i<sentence.length())`. So, the conditions should be replaced, and first check should be `i+1<sentence.length()`

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't adding or removing characters, you may as well just use `String.toCharArray()`:

```
char[] cs = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; ) {
  while (i < cs.length() && !Character.isLetter(cs[i])) ++i;
  int start = i;
  while (i < cs.length() && Character.isLetter(cs[i])) ++i;
  process(cs, start, i);
}
String result = new String(cs);
```

where `process(char[], int startInclusive, int endExclusive)` is a method which jumbles the letters in the array between the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String[] parts = str.split(","); 
// processing parts
String str2 = String.join(",", parts);
```